# Need dynamic inputs to be inserted into database, cannot get it to work

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help to insert some dynamic inputs to database..

What I need is that I have one table that will contain some details, and that insert should get a unique ID in the db. That is easy, but then the headache is in place, I need the dynamic inputs to get inserted into the database in a different table, and then I need them to be able to connect with the user who submitted them.

An example:
I write in the details, and write some stuff in the dynamic inputs. And I submit it. Then I need to be able to see what user submitted what in the dynamic inputs.

Anyone willing to help me with this?

Here is the formcode:

```
<form method="post" action="./paamelding">
<p><label>Fult navn til grupperleder:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="fultnavn" /></p>

<p><label>Gruppeleders alder:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="alder" /></p>

<p><label>Gruppeleders telefon nummer:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="tlf" /></p>

<p><label>Gruppeleders epost adresse:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="epost" /></p>

 <div id="dynamicInput">
     <p><label>Deltaker 1:</label></p>
     <p><input type="text" name="myInputs[]"></p>
 </div>

 <input type="button" value="Legg til et nytt felt" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput')" />

 <button type="submit" name="group_submit">Send inn påmelding!</button>
</form>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Something that was so badly written it was something someone else had come up with, it did not work and it was poorly written. So I threw it away, I do not have it here at the moment either, sorry.

Comment: if you say it was *so badly  written* you must be able to come with a better written solution, right?

Comment: I was hoping that myself, but I tried - and failed, because I am not too sure how to handle the dynamic inputs in a correct way. But there were a lot of code in there that was deprecated, that is why I said it was badly written.

Comment: put here some PHP code, help us help you, I am sure you don't want us to do your job, or at least not for free - what is the price in order to write the backend for that form?

Comment: Kindly provide the code of addInput('dynamicInput') as Form is correct must have error's in addInput('dynamicInput')